# pip3 + is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, rhel

We tried to install different kind of `lxml-python` modules on `rhel 7.X` but without success as the following

```
pip3 install --no-index --find-links /tmp lxml-4.9.2-cp39-cp39-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
ERROR: lxml-4.9.2-cp39-cp39-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

pip3 install --no-index --find-links /tmp lxml-4.9.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
ERROR: lxml-4.9.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

pip3 install --no-index --find-links /tmp lxml-4.9.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
ERROR: lxml-4.9.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

**pip3 version is**

```
pip3 --version
pip 19.3.1 from /etc/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

rhel release is:

```
more /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)

uname -r
3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64

python3 --version
Python 3.8.0
```

Any idea how to solve the problem about  “ `is not a supported wheel on this platform` “

Note - the machine Linux `RHEL 7.X` is without external network so the modules installation are off line

Comment: You can install lxml-python the old-fashioned way: get the source code, make sure the C libraries (dependencies) are installed, then use `pip3 install .` from the base directory of the lxml-python source directory.

Comment: The reason you run into this problem, is likely because the combination of Python 3.9 and RHEL 7 is relatively rare, so there is no easy-to-install binary package for this combination.

Comment: BTW I also try to install it  ( just for test ) with pip2 with the same error ,

Comment: another thing , we have RHEL 7.9 its no so old version ( its the latest from 7.x )

Comment: An up-to-date version doesn't always mean it has a recent Python version. More often, it means the original Python version it came with has the latest bug fixes. So is Python 3.9 the system installed Python3?

Comment: Another thing, about Python versions: you have `pip 19.3.1 from /etc/rh/rh-python38/...` (Python 3.8), but you try to install a *cp39* wheel file (Python 3.9). Have you tried with a cp38 wheel instead?

Comment: I will try to install 38

Comment: yes we successfully installed the version -  lxml-4.9.2-cp38-cp38  , so you mean if for example we have python 3.9 then we need to install the cp39 also ?